# What's wrong with this Perl module?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I am making a very, very simple module (it is the first I've ever wrote):

```
package Master::Math;
use 5.12.4;
use strict;
use warnings;

require Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter)

our %EXPORT_TAGS = ( 
    'all' => [ qw(
        max



=cut

1; # End of Master::Math
```

When I run use this in my program, I get the error

> Invalid version format (non-numeric data) at C:/Perl/lib/Master/Math.pm line 3,
> near "package Master::Math
>
> "
> syntax error at C:/Perl/lib/Master/Math.pm line 3, near "package Master::Math
>
> require Exporter"
> Compilation failed in require at C:\MainDev\myperl\max.pl line 3.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\MainDev\myperl\max.pl line 3.

What do I need to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: For starters, you need to show us the code that the error message refers to.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I did! Actually I forgot to do it at first, but I did.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't there when I read it.  But when you post code, please use the `{}` icon to format it not the `"` icon.  I was about to edit it for you, but I think the way you quoted it messed up the code.  Please re-edit your question, re-paste your module source, select the source code, and click the `{}` icon to format it correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: Your code doesn't produce that error for me with Perl 5.14.1 or 5.10.1 (on MacOS X, if it matters).  Further, it probably wouldn't be line 3 (the `use strict;` line as shown, `package Master::Math;` according to the error message) that was generating the complaint.  If you show the code and the error, please make sure the code exactly matches what you're executing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon on the declaration of `@ISA`.

In `sub max`, `$foo` is undeclared; use `foreach my $foo ...`.

That should get it to compile.  I haven't looked beyond that.

(BTW, I didn't get the same errors you did.  I used perl 5.14.0, `perl -cw master-math.pm`.)