# Invalid version format (version required) at Module/Runtime.pm when executing a perl script that uses Elasticsearch.pm

Tags: perl, elasticsearch, ubuntu-12.04

I'm having issues executing a perl script that uses the Elasticsearch.pm (new version, s lowercased) module.
The script is correct (I've also checked the syntax with perl -c option), but when I try to execute it, I get this error:

```
Invalid version format (version required) at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/Module/Runtime.pm line 349.
```

I googled a lot, but I found nothing... It seems that this error only happens to me :(

P.s.: I'm testing it on an Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to close the question. Anyway, the solution is in the comment I wrote to Neil Lunn:

It was due to the module Elasticsearch.pm, whose version 1.0 is not compatible with new Runtime.pm. I wrote to the developer, and he fixed it. New version is on github elasticsearch-perl. –

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted your code, and this is the likely cause of the problem. But it seems you have a call in your code somewhere to `use_module` from Module::Runtime.

The second argument, which is the version, is not in a valid format.

If you cannot solve it yourself from just this you will need to edit your question to include your code. At least the most likely section.

[https://www.google.com.au/search?q=perl+invalid+version+format](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=perl%20invalid%20version%20format)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204942/2313887

https://metacpan.org/source/ZEFRAM/Module-Runtime-0.014/lib/Module/Runtime.pm#L349

Comment: Hi,
It was due to the module Elasticsearch.pm, whose version 1.0 is not compatible with new Runtime.pm.
I wrote to the developer, and he fixed it. New version is on github elasticsearch-perl.

Comment: You could also downgrade your Module::Runtime distribution to an older version, which helped in my case (not related to Elasticsearch).